# Ubuntu ec2 instance: swap file is disappearing when I stop and then start the instance

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2, swap

My instance swap file is disappearing when I stop and then start the instance.
I have an Ubuntu ec2 instance, and I followed the usual instructions to setup swap space.

these are the mounted file system

```
server@ip-172-22-23-1:~$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/root        62G   27G   36G  43% /
tmpfs           3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           1.6G  2.6M  1.6G   1% /run
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
/dev/xvda15     105M  5.3M  100M   5% /boot/efi
tmpfs           795M  4.0K  795M   1% /run/user/1005
```

the swap space

```
server@ip-172-22-23-1:~$ swapon -s
Filename                Type        Size        Used        Priority
/swapfile               file        16777212    7168        -2
```

fstab

```
server@ip-172-22-23-1:~$ more /etc/fstab 
LABEL=cloudimg-rootfs   /           ext4    discard,errors=remount-ro   0 1
LABEL=UEFI              /boot/efi   vfat    umask=0077                  0 1
LABEL=swap              /swapfile   swap    swap defaults               0 0
```

Is there any way to make the configuration persistent?

Answer (score 1):

Anything you need to survive a stop/start of your EC2 instance cannot be saved to [instance storage](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/InstanceStorage.html):

> The data in an instance store persists only during the lifetime of its
> associated instance. If an instance reboots (intentionally or
> unintentionally), data in the instance store persists. However, data
> in the instance store is lost under any of the following
> circumstances:
>
> - The underlying disk drive fails
> - The instance stops
> - The instance hibernates
> - The instance terminates

You can attach an [EBS volume](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-volumes.html) to your instance and use that for your swap file.

> An EBS volume is off-instance storage that can persist independently
> from the life of an instance.